# How to find a math conference accepting papers?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission

I have written a short math paper which may be suitable for a conference proceeding. However, I don't know how to find an appropriate (mathematical) conference  which accepting papers. Is there any suggestions?

Besides, do I have to actually attend the conference in order to make the paper accepted?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You will find that very few math conferences even publish proceedings, and as such, they do not accept papers but talks. In math (at least theoretical math), publishing is done in journals (and on arXiv. Remember to put the paper on arXiv).

Comment: There are some journals that focus on shorter papers. Mathematical Research Letters is a good one.

Comment: The generic answer is **ask your supervisor or colleagues**. Your peers are the ones knowing which venues are appropriate or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In mathematics, you're very unlikely to find such a conference.  There are a few (the only one that springs to mind is [FPSAC](https://sites.google.com/site/fpsac2016/home)).  There are sometimes proceedings based on conferences, but typically those articles are solicited after the conference from the invited speakers.  The idea of taking submissions of papers before conferences and then judging whether they are appropriate for presentation at the conference is pretty foreign to mathematicians, and publishing in conference proceedings is much lower in prestige than in journals.

Thus, I recommend you submit to a journal instead.